# How to change an instantiated object's color?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just want to change it's color when it gets to a certain point of the camera, and then it goes to the left and changes again. The object is a Gem.

I tried doing this:

```
void Rendercolor()
{
    render =  Gem.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    random = new Color(Random.Range(0, 255), 
    Random.Range(0,255),Random.Range(0,255),255);
}

void Update()
{
    Rendercolor();

    if (direction == DirecaoGameObject.Right)
    {
        Gem.transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime 
        *velocity);
        if (Gem.transform.position.x >= right.position.x)
        {
            render.color = random;
            direction = SortdirecaoGameObject(direction);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it..... Instead of using 0,255 i putted 0f,1f. It did the trick....

Answer (score 0):

A word to your programming style: It is not clear from then name `Rendercolor` what this method does. Besides creating a color, it also gets a render component. Also, it does not return anything, but sets some global fields. The following structure would be clearer.

```
Color CreateRandomColor()
{
    return new Color(Random.Range(0, 255), Random.Range(0, 255), Random.Range(0, 255), 255);
}

void Update()
{
    if (direction == DirecaoGameObject.Right)
    {
        Gem.transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * velocity);
        if (Gem.transform.position.x >= right.position.x)
        {
            // Use local variable here.
            var spriteRenderer =  Gem.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
            spriteRenderer.color = CreateRandomColor();
            direction = SortdirecaoGameObject(direction);
        }
    }
}
```

`spriteRenderer` and color are created inside the nested if. There is no point in creating them in advance in case the if's are not executed.